# Angular FormGroup : unable to find control with path in angular 11

Tags: angular, form-control, dynamic-data-list

**I'm trying to generate form dynamically on the basis of requirement but it is giving an error showing that unable to find control with path:**

here I'm getting an List from API as per that list I'm trying to generate checkboxes dynamically and adding them to formgroup but it is giving error please refer below code for same

> here is code of component :

```
export class QualificationExpComponent implements OnInit {
  
  jobmasterList: any = [];
  checkboxform1: FormGroup;
  public jobcount = 0;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private callapi: ServiceService, private _router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.addCheckboxes();
    this.initializecheckboxform1();

    this.callapi.getDetails().subscribe(res => {
      if (res.data !== null) {
        this.jobmasterList = res.data.jobs;
        this.categoriesList = res.data.jobs[0].category;
        this.subcatList = res.data.jobs[0].category[0].sub_category;
        console.log(this.subcatList)
      }
    })
  }
 
  }
  initializecheckboxform1() {
    this.checkboxform1 = this.formBuilder.group({
      orders: new FormArray([], this.minSelectedCheckboxes(1))
    });
  }
  minSelectedCheckboxes(min = 1) {
    const validator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: FormArray) => {
      const totalSelected = formArray.controls
        // get a list of checkbox values (boolean)
        .map(control => control.value)
        // total up the number of checked checkboxes
        .reduce((prev, next) => next ? prev + next : prev, 0);

      // if the total is not greater than the minimum, return the error message
      return totalSelected >= min ? null : { required: true };
    };
    return validator;
  }
  get ordersFormArray() {
    return this.checkboxform1.controls.orders as FormArray;
  }

  private addCheckboxes() {
    this.jobmasterList.forEach(() => this.ordersFormArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
  }
  get sf() {
    return this.salaryexpForm.controls;
  }
  get rf() {
    return this.remunerationForm.controls;
  }

 
  SelectePrevExperience() {
    const selectedOrderIds = this.checkboxform1.value.orders
    .map((v, i) => v ? this.jobmasterList[i].id : null)
    .filter(v => v !== null);
  console.log(selectedOrderIds);
  console.log(this.checkboxform1.value);
  }
  checkboxform1submit() {
   console.log(this.checkboxform1.value);
  }
}
```

> This is HTML component where i'm trying to bind an data with
> formControlName :

```
<span formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let master of jobmasterList; let i = index">
                    <div *ngIf="i === jobcount">
                    <span class="TextMaroonBold" style="color: #1c8bea;font-weight: bold;"> {{master.description}}
                    </span><br>
                    <span *ngFor="let order of master.category; let j = index">
                        <input type="text" value="{{order.category_id}}" [formControlName]="j" style="display: none;">
                        <span class="TextMaroonBold"> {{order.name}}
                        </span>
                        <div class="ex1">
                            <span *ngFor="let option of order.sub_category; let k = index" class="checkbox">
                        
                                <div class="form-check" style="padding-left: 35px;">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{option.ref_id}}" [formControlName]="k">
                                        {{option.name}}
                                    
                                </div>
                        
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
                </span>
```

> In the console, I see the error below:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'orders -> i'
```

Comment: error is `this.checkboxform1 = this.formBuilder.group({
      orders: new FormArray([], this.minSelectedCheckboxes(1))
    });` here where is formControlName `i` is ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-example-b4d2vg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts this might be helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

First, you should surround all your `fromControlName` properties by `[]` as mentioned in [Angular Binding Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{option.ref_id}}" [formControlName]="i">
```

Secondly, you have nested loops inside your HTML, you must change the variable index `i` for each nested loops:

```html
<div *ngFor="...; let i = index">
    <div *ngFor="...; let j = index"></div>
</div>
```